# Creating database, tables, procedures using stored procedure/function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create database (+schema, data, procedures, roles) using procedure/function - when I call it from c# code.

---

Situation:

I have masterDB database, in which user can create new company. When he creates new company the new database (for example: nike2011) should be created (ddl script: tables + stored procedures would be stored somewhere - in procedure/script?).

If he chooses to copy catalogs from some other database (ex. nike2010, or cocacola2009), the data should be copied from chosen database to database nike2011.

After creating db, I need to grant all sql server users to newly created database.

---

I tried using stored procedure, but I can't create stored procedure inside of stored procedure for creating new database, and I can't use 'use nike2010' in stored procedure.

Hope you understand.

Comment: In general, creating a whole new database (instead  of segmenting your data in a single database) is a bad idea. Be 100% sure what you're doing is the right way of doing it before going too far down this path.

Comment: I expected this comment. Unfortunately, the decision for creating new db for every year wasn't mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to execute dynamic SQL (SQL constructed using strings) using [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), for example.